# mysql insert too slow

Tags: java, mysql, innodb

[mysql server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kulyf.png)
    Here is mysql config, a very simple table, innodb and not much index, but sometimes insert op is too slow, could somebody tell me why?

```
public Long insertCoursewarePage(Env env, Long coursewareId, Integer pageType, String teacherId) throws SQLException {
    env.logTiming("beforeGetConnection");
    Connection conn = MySql.getInst_education_biz().getConnection();
    env.logTiming("afterGetConnection");
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO `courseware_page`(`courseware_id`, `page_type`, `teacher_id`, `create_time`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        env.logTiming("afterPrepareStatement");
        pstmt.setLong(1, coursewareId);
        pstmt.setInt(2, pageType);
        pstmt.setString(3, teacherId);
        pstmt.setLong(4, System.currentTimeMillis());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        env.logTiming("afterExecuteUpdate");
        rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        env.logTiming("afterGetGeneratedKeys");
        if (rs.next()) {
            return rs.getLong(1);
        }
    } finally {
        MySql.closeConnection(rs, pstmt, conn);
    }
    return null;
}
/**
Here is my java code, use jdbc get a connection and I profiled it and the result is below here. 
beforeGetConnection=14
afterGetConnection=20
afterPrepareStatement=20
afterExecuteUpdate=5344
afterGetGeneratedKeys=5345
mysql server is on a dell r820, SSD, 64 core cpu, 320G memory, it seems no any problem.so could anybody tell me why
**/
```

Comment: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4ZN7.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwNwL.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc5sR.png

Comment: Post **all** the relevant code as text please. The code editor exists for that purpose.

Comment: i'm sorry i have no privileges to reply you, the code img is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm3GN.png

Comment: Again, remove the images and include all the relevant code as text by [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44869679/edit).

Comment: @BackSlash code is here

Comment: Is `MySql.closeConnection(rs, pstmt, conn);`a method you wrote yourself ?

Comment: yes it return connection to the pool and close resultset

Answer (score 1):

This could be because everytime you want to insert you open the connection with `Connection conn = MySql.getInst_education_biz().getConnection();` then you perform your queries and close it afterward `MySql.closeConnection(rs, pstmt, conn);`

Your insert time might be low but opening and closing the connection for every query is costly. If your database is frequently queried, you might want to use a Connection Pool that will only "pause" the connection and "resume" it whenever it is needed. Here are some reasons why to use it: https://plumbr.eu/blog/io/acquiring-jdbc-connections-what-can-possibly-go-wrong

Comment: Thank you n0xew, but I'm sure there is no business with get Connection. Because I log the execute time, from the thread begin to `env.logTiming("beforeGetConnection");` the program cost 14ms, and when it run to `Connection conn = MySql.getInst_education_biz().getConnection();`it is 20 ms, it means get a connection only cost 6ms, and you can see other cost below the code. Most time costs on `pstmt.executeUpdate();` I tryed this sql on mysql server cli, it comes to the same result.

Comment: My mysql server hardware configuration also in the comments below my java code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the database does some ressource freeing on its side after the connection is closed, thus taking more time to process possible incoming connections and queries. This would of course depend on the frequency of your queries.

Anyway, updated my answer to use a `ConnectionPool`, which can only help you in case of other issues.

Comment: I have already have a ConnectionPool,I said the last raw return the connection to ConnectionPool

Comment: sorry, did not saw your reply. Also, I cannot see on your screenshots, what amount of time separates each query ?

Comment: lt slows sometime

Comment: I meant what amount of time separates each call to your `insertCoursewarePage` method ? Is this method called very frequently or sometimes ? Because if it's the first it could cause an overload on the db, and you may want to consider using `batches` instead of one-by-one queries.

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/C4ZN7.png 
[4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uwNwL.png 
[5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xc5sR.png

Comment: This method call when user clicked add courseware_page button, not frequently, and code server could not save temp courseware_page, so I did not use batches. The problem is this table is not too large, but insert op is too slow, I want to know the reason.